# How to build a tree in C# given just the child elements?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, tree

I have a set of elements that belong to a tree. I only care about the ancestors, I don't care about the children. For example I want the tree to look like this:

1. Barbeque Supplies*
2. Household cleaning Supplies
  1. Air fresheners
      1. Car Airfreshner*
  2. Paper Towels*
3. Utensils
  1. Forks*

The only input I'm given are the starred elements. So I have something like this:

```
List<Categories> categories = new List<Categories>("Forks", "Paper Towels", "Car Airfreshner", "Barbeque Supplies");
```

Categories looks like this:

```
string Id;
Category Parent;
IList<Category> Children;
Category RootNode; // e.g., "Household cleaning supplies"
```

Unfortunately, the complete tree is rather large ... ~17,000 items. But the list basically never changes, so if I have to do anything to massage it to make access easier, I'm willing to do that.

I'm using NHibernate and I've tried a couple of methods:

```
public IList<Categories> CompleteTree(IList<Categories> inputList) {
            var result = new List<Categories>();
            foreach (var item in inputList) {
                var recursiveItem = categoryRepository.Get(item);

                while (recursiveItem != null) {
                    result.Add(recursiveItem);
                    recursiveItem = item.Parent;
                }
            }    
            return result;
        }
```

That hits the database a lot, anyway around this? I'm using NHibernate 2 if there's any slick code for that.

I've seen [Ayende's blog post,](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/28/nhibernate-tips-amp-tricks-efficiently-selecting-a-tree.aspx) but he's going down children items, where I'm given the child items to start out with and I'm working my way up. Or I could be doing the same thing as him but just don't realize it.

Edit: added categoriesRepository to make it more clear that I'm hitting the database.

Comment: If you're only given the child elements there is no way to build the Tree. When would you know to add a new parent item?

Comment: This is all taking place within my data repository. I already have the entire tree in a database. I'm trying to retrieve the relevant parts of the tree given a set of elements within that tree. The problem is that you're hitting the database multiple times with the while statement, even with memory caching. I assumed there was a better way to go about this.

Comment: I should add that ideally this probably would go better in a graph/document based database, but I'd like to not setup a new database for this just one thing. I suppose I could store the hierarchy with each category object as a json string, then when I load it from the db, deserialize it. I was hoping for a better way to go about it.

Comment: How do you know which parent goes to each child?  Is the relationship information in the database, if so, then what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** As I have no experience with NHibernate, I'm going out on a limb here.

[Ayende's blog post](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/28/nhibernate-tips-amp-tricks-efficiently-selecting-a-tree.aspx) uses a `join fetch` statement, which is NHibernate-specific SQL, called HQL. Since NHibernate is just another layer on top of the database and SQL databases aren't designed to handle hierarchies, it would still require recursive queries to fetch the entire tree.

But Ayende also mentions in [one of his comments](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/28/nhibernate-tips-amp-tricks-efficiently-selecting-a-tree.aspx#33821) that it's easier to query a tree, if both the **direct and indirect relations** are stored in the database. He refers to a structure like this:

```
Ancestor                      Descendant        IsChild
-------------------------------------------------------
Household cleaning Supplies   Air fresheners    True
Household cleaning Supplies   Paper Towels      True
Household cleaning Supplies   Car Airfreshner   False
Air fresheners                Car Airfreshner   True
Utensils                      Forks             True
```

Ayende uses a `Level` column that indicates the depth of a node in the tree, which could be used to limit the depth of the tree in the query. But `IsChild` will demonstrate the principle as well.

#### Finding ancestors

Given the descendant node *Car Airfreshner*, you can select all ancestor nodes in one query. You can reconstruct parent-child relations from these nodes by checking the `IsChild` value.

```
SELECT * FROM TreeRelations WHERE Descendant = 'Car Airfreshner'
```

#### Creating a tree

Given the ancestor node *Household cleaning Supplies*, you can build a tree starting from this node by selecting all the descendants in a single query. The `IsChild` value can be used to find parent-child relations.

```
SELECT * FROM TreeRelations WHERE Ancestor = 'Household cleaning Supplies'
```

#### Both queries combined

To get the entire tree for any given node, you can combine both queries to retrieve all ancestors and descendants and build a tree from that:

```
SELECT * FROM TreeRelations WHERE Descendant = 'Entry node' OR Ancestor = 'Entry node'
```